# setState hook is always 1 step behind when trying to filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to make a filter menu where you can filter on different options. I'm trying to do this with the setState hook. I define the options where you can filter on.

```
const [phaseId, setPhaseId] = useState(0);
const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState(0);
const [themeId, setThemeId] = useState(0);
const [districtId, setDistrictId] = useState(0);
const [newProjects, setNewProjects] = useState(projects);
```

If a user clicks on a specific option. The value of the specific option needs to change.

```
{phases.map((phase) => (
  <label htmlFor={phase.phase}>
    <input
      id={phase.phase}
      type="radio"
      name="phase"
      onClick={(e) => handlePhase(phase.id)}
    />
    <p>{phase.phase}</p>
  </label>
))}
```

I'm updating the state with the setState hook and call my filter function after that. In my filter function, I check if the values of the options are 0 or not. If they are not 0, they have to filter over the array.

```
const handlePhase = (id) => {
  setPhaseId(id);
  filter();
};

const filter = () => {
  let filter = projects;

  if (phaseId != 0) {
    filter = filter.filter((x) => x.phase_id == phaseId);
  }
  if (categoryId != 0) {
    filter = filter.filter((x) => x.category_id == categoryId);
  }
  if (themeId != 0) {
    filter = filter.filter((x) => x.theme_id == themeId);
  }
  if (districtId != 0) {
    filter = filter.filter((x) => x.district_id == districtId);
  }

  setNewProjects(filter);
};
```

The problem I have is that the setState hook is always 1 step behind. For example, when I click on a phase with id 3. The state of `phaseId` will be 3 on the next render and won't update immediately. I'm using a submit button for now, but I want the UI to update immediately. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing React with missing `key` property. You need to append one to your `<label>` element (i.e. `<label key={phase.phase}..`)

Comment: The `htmlFor` attribute is being used correctly in the JSX here (as you pointed out @YevgenGorbunkov). It is however missing a `key` attribute as you pointed out in the `map`

Comment: @Dominik: I didn't say *'replace'*, I said *'append'*

Comment: Yeah what confused me was your usage of the word `confusing` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because updating the state in react works in an async way.
means that your component will receive the new state on the re-render

so instead of calling the *filter* function inside *handlePhase* function use useEffect with phase as a dependency in the dependency array.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  filter();
},[phase])
```

check this out and try to remove the comments from useEffect and compare the results
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-varahamihira-ql9wz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

The shown projects are not a state. They are a value that can be derived from other states, namely the original projects and all the filters. Just compute it on every render:

```
 const shownProjects = projects  
   .filter(/*...*/);

 return shownProjects.map(/*...*/);
```

If you run into performance problems, use `useMemo` and debounce the filter values.